# Was my question removed? If so, why?

Tags: discussion

I recently posted here on meta asking for us to consider why we down vote questions. I can't find it.  Was it removed?  Can I ask why?  If, in fact, it was removed with no explanation, it sort of reinforces the point I was making about discouraging questions.

Comment: Huh. I don’t see it either.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, my mod powers allow me to see it. I found it, and it is indeed deleted.

[image]

Since the deleter is given as "Community bot", your question must have triggered some rule and have been deleted automatically. I don't know the details of these rules, they are probably available somewhere on Meta.Stackexchange. But I suppose that the combination of a negative score and no answers might have been the trigger.

It is questionable whether that is a good trigger for our Meta, where downvotes do not denote bad quality, but simple disagreement, and people are not very active in answering. But I haven't heard of a way to opt out of such a feature - although to be fair, I haven't actively looked out for it either.

I will undelete now and we can see if it disappears again - hopefully, the system will be smart enough to know that a manually undeleted question should not be targeted by automated cleanup.